# Select a option from a filtered cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am new in VBA so i am unable to do this.

I have 21 sheets in a workbook. I want to select a cell in 3rd sheet (which contains a Pivot Table) which I am able to do. This cell B3 contains a filter and I can select from the filtered drop menu on how to sort my data. It contains whether I want to filter by first name OR last name OR all.

My usual routine is first to select by first name, then copy the filtered data and paste it on another sheet. Then come back to the same sheet and filter by last name and then copy the filtered data and paste it on the sheet I pasted the earlier data.

What I need help with is the following:

1. If any or all check boxes are selected then deselect them.
2. Select the first_name checkbox in the filter drop down
3. De-select the first_name box and select the last_name box
4. Finally deselect last_name and then select all checkbox

I have used the following code

```
Public Sub Open_Sheet3()
Workbooks("MASTER.xlsx").Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Activate
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Technology").CurrentPage = _
    "(All)"
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Technology")
.PivotItems("Mobility").Visible = False
.PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
.PivotItems("Enterprise Messaging Tech").Visible = False
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Nishant, welcome to SO! What exactly do you need help one? If you bascially want to automate the process you line out, start recording a macro, do the process above manually - and then take a look at the code (Alt-F11 brings you to the Visual Basic editor)...

Comment: Hi Peter, The thing is that the VBA is viewed by my whole team so sometimes the check boxes in the drop down filter be selected differently. so if I use a recorded macro it will only use the pattern I do thus If any other check box is selected besides the one in the recorded Macro then it poses a problem.

Comment: What I need help with is the following:
1. If any or all check boxes are selected then de-select them.
2. Select the first_name ceckbox in the filter dropdown
3. De-select the first_name box and select the last_name box

Comment: When you talk about checkboxes: do you mean the checkboxes of an Autofilter, i.e. you copy the filtered raw data - or do you mean the filter of a pivot table - and you copy it's results? Regarding the VBA: What you ask for requires VBA - your team will need to accept that.

Comment: I know how i'll copy the result. I am talking about the pivot table filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should do what you want. Just replace the names of worksheet/pivot table/pivot field and fill in the `copyStuff` sub.

```
Private Sub YourProcedure()
    SelectItem "first_name"
    CopyStuff

    SelectItem "last_name"
    CopyStuff

    SelectItem "all" 'in case you have an element called "all"
    CopyStuff

    SelectAll 'In case you mean the "(All)" 'element', i.e. include everything
    CopyStuff

End Sub

Private Sub SelectItem(strItemName As String)
    Dim i As Integer

    'Change to your worksheet/pivot talbe/pivot field name!
    With Worksheets("Sheet 1").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("a")

        .PivotItems(1).Visible = True 'at least one item always needs to be visible
        For i = 2 To .PivotItems.Count
            .PivotItems(i).Visible = False
        Next
        .PivotItems(strItemName).Visible = True
        If .PivotItems(1).Name <> strItemName Then .PivotItems(1).Visible = False

    End With
End Sub

Private Sub SelectAll()
    Dim i As Integer

    'Change to your worksheet/pivot talbe/pivot field name!
    With Worksheets("Sheet 1").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("a")
        For i = 1 To .PivotItems.Count
            .PivotItems(i).Visible = True
        Next
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub CopyStuff()
    'Your code goes here
End Sub
```

Some explanation:

If you want to deselect items of a pivot field, you need to make sure that there's at least on item selected at any time. Therefore you cannot unselect all and then select your desired item - but rather select the first item, unselect all other, select your item and unselect the first item unless it is your item. That's what `SelectItem` is doing

Comment: Thanks Peter... I'll give it a go.. I am sure it'll help me do what I want.....
And sorry If My question was unclear... this was my first question on stack overflow...
Thanks for the help

Comment: You're welcome! Don't forget to close the question by accepting the answer once your issue is solved...

Comment: Hey Peter There is some problems while running the code.
1. in {    Private Sub SelectItem(strItemName As String)} the Line {    If .PivotItems(1).Name  strItemName Then .PivotItems(1).Visible = False} is showing error
2. I put an = after .name then error was unable to set the visible property.
3. then I changed it to True from False then what it did was first select the first value. then instead of deselcting the first one and select the next one, it selected the next one while the first one was visible.

What should I do ?? any suggestions.

Comment: it actually stated "<>" (where you placed the "="), but I forgot to quote it. It's updated now, give it a try. Don't change it to "TRUE".

Comment: @NishantKumar: I just added some explanations, too. Hope it helps!

Comment: Yup It works. I have been at it for hours now. MAN.... you guys really are geniuses at this.

Comment: Hey Peter I tried this on a similar pivot table but it has far more items. I changed the details of table name etc... according to my need. But This `    SelectItem` does not work. It gets stuck at `    .PivotItems(1).Visible = True` and shows unable to set property....